# How to install postgres 9.4 on mac

Tags: macos, postgresql

I cannot find any details related to this. Can someone please point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: With **homebrew**, namely `brew install postgresql@9.4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With brew by default, it installs 10.x. I was able to figure out as Mark explained above with command "brew install postgresql@9.4"